# British slang: larl

Tags: british-english, slang

I've seen this word a couple of times in twitter and I've not gotten a clear definition. A friend of mine wrote a mock British text that went like this "al av ya mum ya larl cunt" so that might give context.

Comment: My guess is the specific 'larl' means _little_. Overall, I would not use the mentioned phrase in any but the most intimate company...

Comment: Well that's quite obvious, I wasn't planning on repeating the whole phrase unless I wanted to get kicked out of wherever I may be at the time of use. But yeah, that seems like a good guess.

Answer (score 5):

For the sake of completeness:

> al av ya mum ya larl cunt

al = I will -> I'll -> ah'll

av = have -> 'ave (in this case *have* has overtly sexual connotations as in "have sexual relations with")

ya = your -> ya'r -> ya

mum = mother (not really slang)

ya = you -> ya

larl = little -> lirle -> lahrl

And the last word is so commonly used I feel I need not explain it :)

As I said in the comment, but also for future reference: do not use sentences like this unless you are in really intimate company. Not all strangers are likely to react well to statements of this kind :)

Comment: ya = your in this case, wouldn't you say? "I'll have sexual relations with *your* mother"

Comment: Yes, I would, and I did. There are two ya's in the sentence, and I included both in order. :)